# OSX - Service does not show the localized Menu Title string

Tags: cocoa, service, osx-lion

I have a Cocoa application. This hooks up into OSX Service Menu. I have created three `ServicesMenu.strings` for `en.lproj`, `zh-Hans.lproj` and `hi-IN.lproj` for localizing the Service Menu Title. *The problem is OSX does seem to be using the localized text at all.*

### Info.plist (relevant portion)

```
<key>NSServices</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSKeyEquivalent</key>
        <key>NSMenuItem</key>
        <dict>
            <key>default</key>
            <string>CreateHere</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSMessage</key>
        <string>createHere</string>
        <key>NSPortName</key>
        <string>CreateHereFilesService</string>
        <key>NSRequiredContext</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSApplicationIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.finder</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSSendFileTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.folder</string>
        </array>
        <key>NSUserData</key>
        <string>create</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

### ServicesMenu.strings (en.lproj)

```
/* 
  ServicesMenu.strings
*/

/* default */
"CreateHere" = "Create File Here";
```

*On the Services Menu I can see the option `CreateHere` instead of `Create File Here`.*

## Update

If this helps. Here is the output of `/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -dump_pboard`

```
{
    CFPrincipalLocalizations =     (
        English
    );
    CFVendedServices =     (
                {
            NSBundleIdentifier = "com.applegrew.apple.service.CreateHereFiles";
            NSBundlePath = "/Users/applegrew/Library/Services/CreateHereFiles.app";
            NSMenuItem =             {
                default = CreateHere;
            };
            NSMessage = createHere;
            NSPortName = CreateHereFilesService;
            NSRequiredContext =             {
                NSApplicationIdentifier = "com.apple.finder";
            };
            NSSendFileTypes =             (
                "public.folder"
            );
            NSUUID = <199fd7c0 cdd146fb 9a564a93 231b23f9>;
            NSUserData = create;
        }
    );
    CFVersion = 2;
}
```

*Unlike for other services (not shown above) `NSMenuItem` does does not have any entry `English`.* Does this have anything to do with, that I do not have any `English.lproj`, instead I have `en.lproj`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced the same problem today while adding service to my application.

Everything works except the localizations.

Fixed the issue by running these commands:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -flush

/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -update
```

#### According English.lproj

> Does this have anything to do with, that I do not have any
>   English.lproj, instead I have en.lproj?

English.lproj is obsolete, use en.lproj instead. From Apple docs:

> For language designations, you can use either the ISO 639-1 or ISO 639-2 conventions. The ISO 639-1 specification uses a two-letter code to identify a language and is the preferred way to identify languages.

Look at Internationalization Programming Topics (Language and Locale Designations → Language Designations) for more info.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144-SW1